# Landscape application layout wrong while changing its orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am developing a landscape application with orientation `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`, except one view controller( used for uploading image) having orientation `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`.

**How orientation change should ideally work**

1. When users plan to upload image, orientation change from  `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight` to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`,
2. When uploading finished, change orientation `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`, .

**Issue:**

When I tap the icon then into the application, the application layout is right, but if I flat device on the desk for times, next time I get into, application layout is wrong.

**For example:**

First time:

```
aView.width = 568 * 0.6; 
aView.height = 320 * 0.6;
```

[image]

but in other cases:

```
aView.width = 320 * 0.6;
aView.height = 568 * 0.6;
```

seems like width and height exchanged

[image]

Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Show screen shot of your UI. Landscape and portrait both.

Comment: Question is poorly formatted, please format you question to make it easier for us

Comment: Question has been edited, can you help me fix the issue

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually using auto layout here if you're setting the width and height directly. In what view method are you setting the view's size?